# Time evolution of the operators vs. the expectation values

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differential-equations, time-evolution

The time evolution of a quantum mechanical operator $A$ (without explicit time dependence) is given by the Heisenberg equation

$$ \frac{d}{dt}A = \frac{i}{\hbar} \left[H,A\right] \tag{1}$$

where $H$ is the system's Hamiltonian. The time evolution of the corresponding expectation value is given by the Ehrenfest theorem

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left\langle A\right\rangle = \frac{i}{\hbar} \left\langle \left[H,A\right]\right\rangle \tag{2} $$

However, as I have noticed, these can yield differential equations of different forms if $\left[H,A\right]$ contains expressions that do not "commute" with taking the expectation value. For example, let

$$\left[H,A\right]=\frac{dA}{df} \tag{3}$$

for some quantum number $f$. The states used for taking the expectation values in (2) clearly depend on $a$. From (1) and (2) the different time evolutions calculated using (3) are

$$ \frac{d}{dt}A = \frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{dA}{df} \tag{4}$$
and
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left\langle A\right\rangle = \frac{i}{\hbar}\left\langle \frac{dA}{df}\right\rangle \tag{5}$$

Note that clearly (5) is not the same as

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left\langle A\right\rangle = \frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{d\left\langle A\right\rangle}{df}\tag{6}$$

which I would have expected, since then the equations looks equal to (4).

Did I make some mistake? Is this correct? What is the difference between (4)-(6)?
Clearly, (4) and (6) give rise to the same solution (*one for the operator and one for the expectation value*) since the differential equations are the same, while this may not be the case for (5). In fact, from (5) alone, I don't see a clear way on how to construct a solution since $\left\langle A\right\rangle$ does not occur on the right hand side.

Comment: where does (3) come from?

Comment: Isn't it two physically completely different things, if I observe how that state in which a system is evolves by time, or if I investigate the time evolution of the _operator_ itself?

Comment: You've skipped an $i/\hbar$ in (3) needed for (4).

Comment: @Phoenix87 That's just a "pathological example".

Comment: @CosmasZachos I see. I add that factor to the resulting equations.

Comment: It's then clear from (3) that *A* is solely a function of $t-i\hbar f$, which is the time-shifted Heisenberg picture operator when *f* is imaginary.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, that's true. What I mean is that this is not true for $\left\langle\cdot\right\rangle$ as the states used for the expectation value may depend on $f$. Which is why (5) and (6) are not equivalent (and (6) is wrong...?).

Comment: I see... in sharp contrast to the time-independent Heisenberg states... Can probably investigate with a simple example.

Comment: So (5) is correct, and (6) is wrong, as per your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564258/swapping-expectation-value-of-derived-operator-with-derivative-of-expectation-va). A similarity of operator equations need not automatically transfer to expectation values.

Answer (score 3):

The "example" eq. (3) here is kind of a red herring. Let's just take the evolution equation eq. (1) and Ehrenfest's theorem eq. (2). What you're asking about is that taking the expectation value of eq. (1) and using eq. (2) results in
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} \langle A\rangle}{\mathrm{d}t} = \left \langle \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}\right\rangle,$$
which you seem to think isn't true, but the fact that taking the expectation value commutes with the time derivative is exactly the content of Ehrenfest's theorem.

Your example is just re-parametrizing the time evolution of the Heisenberg operator by $f = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar} t$, so this doesn't change anything. That you are really just reparametrizing you can see by plugging eq. (3) into eq. (1), yielding
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}f},$$
meaning $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}$ by the chain rule.

Comment: Does that always work? What if, for example $f$ is the crystal momentum? (I have seen this in one lecture) Or what if $f$ is the spatial coordinate in a 1D system?

Comment: @HerpDerpington It follows directly from the second equation in my post, but note that it only holds in the context of the specific observable $A$. I'm not claiming that $f=\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}t$ holds in some general sense (which would be unclear to begin with), just that for this specific $A$ you get the expression for $A(f)$ by plugging $t = -\mathrm{i}\hbar f$ into $A(t)$.

Comment: "which you seem to think isn't true" that was a little bit misleading, what i actually wanted to say is that $\left\langle dA/df \right\rangle \neq d\left\langle A \right\rangle /df$. You cannot swap this in the general case. (Derivatives in $f$, not in $t$)

Comment: See also my comment to @CosmasZachos under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $[H,A]$ is *always* the time derivative of $A$, modulo constants. If you want something physically different from a time derivative, then you should change the "generator" (of translations in time, i.e. time evolution) $H$. For example, the momentum operator $p$ generates translations, so $[p,A]$ gives you the spatial derivative of $A$ along the direction of $p$. That is, modulo constants, you always have $[p, A]=\nabla A$.

Comment: How does this answer the question on expectations?